# Mysqli - ayuda multiple consulta

Tags: php, mysqli

Necesito consultar los siguientes id donde se cumpla lo siguiente:

Valores que ingresa el usuario de 1 a 5 (personas por habitacion ),y tengo que obtener los id's de los Hoteles donde se cumple que hay lugar por ejemplo;

**HABITACION-1**: 2 PASAJEROS;

**HABITACION-2**: 3 PASAJEROS;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

BASE DE DATOS:

**RESULTADO CORRECTO 1=**

```
        FECHA:18/09/2018;
        ID:HOTEL100001;
        DOBLE:CUPO 1;
        TRIPLE:CUPO 1;
        CUADRUPLE:CUPO 1;
```

**RESULTADO CORRECTO 2=**

```
        FECHA:18/09/2018;
        ID:HOTEL100002;
        DOBLE:CUPO 0;
        TRIPLE:CUPO 4;
        CUADRUPLE:CUPO 0;
```

**RESULTADO INCORRECTO 3=**

```
        FECHA:18/09/2018;
        ID:HOTEL100003;
        DOBLE:CUPO 0;
        TRIPLE:CUPO 1;
        CUADRUPLE:CUPO 0;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como hago para buscar en forma excluyente?

Gracias por la ayuda

Consulta mysqli

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","pass","db");
                    /* verificar conexión */
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                        exit();
                    }
                    /* crear una sentencia preparada */

```
                $cupo_habitacion1=1;
                $personashabitacion1=2;
                $cupo_habitacion2=1;
                $personashabitacion2=2;
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                SELECT id_hotel from cupo_tarifa_hoteles WHERE capacidad_habitacion>=? AND cupo_hotel >=?
                INTERSECT
                SELECT id_hotel from cupo_tarifa_hoteles WHERE capacidad_habitacion >=? AND cupo_hotel >=? ")) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $personashabitacion1,$habitacion1,$personashabitacion2,$habitacion2);
                    /* ejecutar la consulta */
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    /* ligar variables de resultado */
                     mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id_hotel);
                    /* obtener valor */

                    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                        echo $id_hotel;


                    }

                    /* cerrar sentencia */
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                /* cerrar conexión */
                $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Hola, has probado algo? Tienes algún ejemplo de la tabla de datos sobre la que quieres consultar?  Así es muy complejo ayudarte. Echa un ojo a esta guía, a ver si mejorando la pregunta podemos ayudarte mejor!! https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hola Ale , ahi subi un print de pantalla , fijate si podes ayudarme,gracias

Comment: genial!! deja que le eche un ojo plz,

Comment: Necesito consultar los siguientes id donde se cumpla lo siguiente:  <- Qué IDS??? necesitas sacar los ID de los hoteles??

Valores que ingresa el usuario de 1 a 5 <- 1 a 5 qué?? peras? manzanas???


tengo que obtener donde se cumple por ejemplo; <--- Dónde se cumple, qué???

Comment: Intenta formular bien el enunciado, explicando en cada caso lo que necesitas. No ahorres palabras, ya que hacerlo rápido no lleva más que a hacerlo mal!!! :)

Comment: Los "ids" son los hoteles donde se cumpla lo ingresado por el usuario , 1 a 5 son la capacidad de personas en las dos habitaciones ,

Comment: cómo en las **dos** habitaciones??? no te entiendo....

Comment: ah... o sea, quieres:

Buscar los hoteles que, tengan el número de habitaciones libres, con esa capacidad?? 

Es decir, si quiero dos habitaciones para dos personas, que quieres filtrar??las que tienen más... las que tienen justo ese tamaño...  .. tienes que detallar más lo que quieres!!!

Comment: Puse en 2 habitaciones, ya que si me ayudas a resolver anidando 2 consultas (imagino) , seria exactamente igual en el caso de 3 o 4 habitaciones

Comment: pero es que no sé qué quiers buscar.... Ahí veo que tienes numero de habitaciones, y el numero que hay en cada una.... asi que no sé si ese número es un mínimo, o debe ser la habitación del mismo número de las que aparecen en cada casilla, y tampoco sé si el hotel que deba aparecer, debe tener todas las habitaciones libres....  Es decir... No explicas realmente lo que necesitas.

Por qué no pruebas a reformular despacio tu pregunta, poniendo frases completas y claras??

Comment: Podría ser que quieras saber en qué hotel están TODAS las habitaciones uqe pides, o que te diga "dónde tienes" esas habitaciones... .o ...

Comment: Ale se tiene que cumplir que cupo sea mayor igual a la cantidad de habitaciones selecciónadas donde también la capacidad de las habitaciones selecciónadas sea mayor o igual a las disponibles

Comment: Quiero cuatro habitaciones, donde Habitacion 1 = 2 pax , Habitacion 2 = 3 Pax. 

Y ahora:
Cupo debe ser mayor de 2... mayor de 3..,. mayor de 4... ????? O mayor de (2+3)*4 ?¿??¿?¿¿ no queda claro.....

Comment: De veras que si a mi me dejas eso en un selector de habitaciones de hotel, te juro, que no sabría que poner...  quizá tú lo tengas claro, pero no hay modo de entenderlo...

Comment: Ahora mirandolo... si pones 4 habitaciones, te deja elegir lo que quieres de cada una, y por eso hay 4??? O_O joer...

Comment: ok... pillandolo... creo...

Comment: Genio gracias Ale ,perdón si no me explique bien

Comment: naaah, se hace lo que se puede!!! echa un ojo a la respuesta, a ver si te vale!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes ir haciendo Intersecciones de conjuntos.

Es decir, el hotel que te valga, será el resultado de buscar:

```
1.- El hotel donde haya al menos, 1 habitación de 2,   
2.- De la lista anterior, deberás buscar los que tengan una de 3  
3.- De la lista anterior, deberás buscar los que tengan otra de 2  
4.- De la lista anterior, deberás buscar los que tengan una de 1
```

Es decir, 4 queries que se deben "juntar/cruzar"

Por tanto, debería ser algo como:

```
--Habitacion A
SELECT id_hotel from HOTELES where capacidad_habitacion = 2 and cupo_hotel > 0
INTERSECT
SELECT id_hotel from HOTELES where capacidad_habitacion = 3 and cupo_hotel > 0
INTERSECT
SELECT id_hotel from HOTELES where capacidad_habitacion = 2 and cupo_hotel > 0
INTERSECT
SELECT id_hotel from HOTELES where capacidad_habitacion = 1 and cupo_hotel > 0
```

El problema, es que al hacer eso, no estás teniendo en cuenta que el cupo del hotel, debe actualizarse (si has tenido en cuenta la primera habitacion de dos personas, no vale si el hotel solo tiene una de dos personas)

Por tanto, deberías antes sumarizar las habitaciones del mismo número de clientes, y por tanto, así sabrías directamente cuántas.

```
SELECT id_hotel from HOTELES where capacidad_habitacion = 2 and cupo_hotel > 1
INTERSECT
SELECT id_hotel from HOTELES where capacidad_habitacion = 3 and cupo_hotel > 0
INTERSECT
SELECT id_hotel from HOTELES where capacidad_habitacion = 1 and cupo_hotel > 0
```

De este modo buscas un hotel con 2 habitaciones de 2 personas, 1 de 3  y 1 de 1.

Espero que te ayude a plantearlo

El operador que buscas, es [INTERSECT ( chequea aqui sus docs)](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/intersect.php)

Comment: De todos modos, y observando, el tema está en que depende de si quieres mostrar habitaciones de 3 personas cuando pides una de 2... porque también cabrían . Sería cosa de cambiar los >= que he puesto, por iguales reales

Comment: He dejado con iguales reales, para que no de resultados extraños

Comment: Ale , hice la consulta , y no muestra nada , imagino me estoy comiendo algo, podes chequearla? Mil gracias de verdad!!!

Comment: Leonardo, yo no sé qué datos hay en toda tu tabla ni si hay las habitaciones que buscas.... debes chequearlos tú... asegúrate que tengas esas habitaciones ......

Comment: Escribo solo para darte las gracias alejandro , si estabas en lo correcto solo que MariaDB no soporta INTERSECT  , pero si JOIN y es exactamente igual , mil mil gracias!!!